# IMemoryCache issues, cannot convert to string?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I can't enter the statement if (ConvertedAccessTokenCache.Contains(accessToken)) when I send a request in Postman, I have to check if the AccessTokenCache contains (accessToken) <- Authorization:Bearer c2E6dGVsZWFkcmU1NSxudA==....

But when it checks if it contains I get "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache" as result when holding mouse over that point..

Any ideas what I am missing?

```
namespace ....Security.Token
    {
        public class TokenManager
        {
            private readonly IMemoryCache AccessTokenCache;
            private readonly IMemoryCache RefreshTokenCache;
            private CancellationTokenSource ctsAccess;
            private CancellationTokenSource ctsRefresh;

            private readonly uint RefreshTokenValidTime = 60 * 60 * 10; //seconds
    #if DEBUG
            private readonly uint TokenExpirationTime = 60 * 60 * 2; //seconds
    #else
            private readonly uint TokenExpirationTime = 60 * 5; //seconds
    #endif

            public TokenManager()
            {
                AccessTokenCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
                RefreshTokenCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
                ctsAccess = new CancellationTokenSource(60 * 60 * 2);
                ctsRefresh = new CancellationTokenSource(60 * 60 * 10);
            }

            public long ValidateToken(string accessToken)
            {
                var ConvertedAccessTokenCache = AccessTokenCache.ToString();

                if (ConvertedAccessTokenCache.Contains(accessToken))
                {
                    var token = (TokenResponse)AccessTokenCache.Get(accessToken);

                    var createdDate = GetCreatedDate(accessToken);
                    var validToDate = createdDate.AddSeconds(token.expires_in);

                    var clientId = GetClientId(accessToken);

                    if (validToDate > SystemTime.Now())
                    {
                        return clientId;
                    }
                }

                return -1L;
            }

        }
    }




public UserEntity GetUser(string credentials)
        {
            var token = new TokenManager();
            var clientId = token.ValidateToken(credentials);
            if (clientId == -1)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var user = Execute(context =>
            {
                var command = new GetCommand<UserEntity>(c => c.UserDataAccess.GetUser(clientId));
                return command.Execute(null, false, context);
            });

            return user;
        }
```

Comment: And the code where you call `ValidateToken(...)`.... ???

Comment: edited now, sorry for missing that!

Comment: Then you need to go further up. Seems like you are calling `cache.ToString()` somewhere instead of `cache.GetString(...)`

Comment: I am calling var ConvertedAccessTokenCache = AccessTokenCache.ToString();, problem is GetString is not available :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AccessTokenCache` is an instance of MemoryCache and when you call `ToString()` you call it's [default implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns the full-qualified name.

You need to call `TryGetValue` or one of the extension methods like `AccessTokenCache.Get<String>("key")`.

Extension methods may require to declare. You need to call `TryGetValue` or one of the extension methods like `using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` before they become available.

```
public long ValidateToken(string accessToken)
{
    // Get<TokenResponse> or TryGetValue will return default value if not found
    // which is null in case of string and classes
    var token = AccessTokenCache.Get<TokenResponse>(accessToken);

    if (token != null)
    {
        var createdDate = GetCreatedDate(accessToken);
        var validToDate = createdDate.AddSeconds(token.expires_in);

        var clientId = GetClientId(accessToken);

        if (validToDate > SystemTime.Now())
        {
            return clientId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped!